# least common multiple (for a range of numbers)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Trying to understand this solution for find the least common multiple in a range of numbers. Need someone to explain why the 'break' is needed.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
  let min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
  let multiple = 0;
  let multipleFound = false;

  while (multipleFound === false) {
    multiple += max;
    for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
        console.log(i)
      if (multiple % i !== 0) {
        multipleFound = false;
        break;

      } else {
        multipleFound = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return multiple;
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1,5]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about the percentage symbol (%)? [It's called modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

So, it looks like your script breaks the loop (sets `multipleFound` to `false`) when `multiple` 'remaining value after division' by `i` is not equal to `0` (`!==`).

If you need more information on the Math in general:
[Information on Least Commons](https://www.mathsisfun.com/least-common-denominator.html)

Comment: yes, I had trouble understanding that part. The code is clearer now that you mention the remainder statement for the break thanks